# Convert HTML input tag to Rails erb templating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have an HTML form I'm looking to convert to ERB templating for my Ruby on Rails application. I'm not sure how to convert the `required autofocus` attributes into an erb template. The rest of the code is straight forward.

HTML

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

ERB

```
 <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Email address' %>
```

How do I add the `required autofocus` attributes to the ERB markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **autofocus: true and required: true** like this:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Email address', :autofocus => true, :required => true %>
```

Comment: What about the `required` attribute?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the required and autofocus attributes are mutually exclusive. You're only incorporating one of them in the erb markup?